# C# ASP.NET Metódo de busca por parametro retornando Erro 500 Internal Server Erro

Tags: c#, asp.net

Boa tarde,estou tendo um problema com um método que busca os produtos e retorna um especifico segundo o código passado. Estou recebendo o erro 500 Internal Server Error quando tento usar a url http://localhost:52444/api/produto/1 para chama-lo. Entretanto a busca pela lista de produtos inteira funciona naturalmente. Alguma ideia? segue código

***Código:***

```
namespace ControleDeEstoqueAPI_.Controllers
{

    public class ProdutoConsultController : ApiController
    {

        [Route("api/Produto")]
        // GET api/ProdutoConsult
        public ObjectResult<uspConsultarProduto_Result> Get()
        {
            ControleDeEstoqueEntities entity = new ControleDeEstoqueEntities();
            var result = entity.uspConsultarProduto(null);
            return result;
        }

        [Route("api/Produto/{cod}")]
        // GET api/ProdutoConsult/5
        public List<produto> Get(int cod)
        {
            ControleDeEstoqueEntities entity = new ControleDeEstoqueEntities();
            List<produto> MyList = new List<produto>();
            var result = from produto in entity.produto where produto.pro_cod == cod select produto;
            MyList.AddRange(result);

            return MyList;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trocando o corpo do método foi o bastante,eu fiz assim

***Código:***

```
[Route("api/Produto/{cod}")]
// GET api/ProdutoConsult/5
public DataTable Get(int cod)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ControleDeEstoque;Integrated Security=True");
        DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Produto where pro_cod like '%" + cod + "%'", con);
        da.Fill(tabela);
        return tabela;
}
```

Ele está me retornando o resultado direitinho.